# Bing/Microsoft OAuth Refresh token expiration

Tags: bing, bing-api, bing-ads-api

Do we need to save and make Bing API calls with an access token or we can do it with a refresh token?  If we can do it with a refresh token
Do we need manually update the Refresh token to be able to do Bing API calls? or it does not have an expiration date or refresh happens automatically and we shouldn't worry about it?